# Return de uma função em Pyton

Tags: python, return

Pessoal como faço pra retornar somente a lista dessa função sem executar os comandos de print e input
que estão dentro ?

```
def entrada_soma():
    parcela1 = list()
    parcela2 = list()
    print("Digite a opção desejada :")
    print("[1] - Valores pelo Teclado / [2] - Gerar aleatoriamente")
    entrada = int(input())
    print("Quantos inteiros cada sequência terá ?")
    n = int(input())
    if entrada == 1:
        print("Digite a sequência de inteiros da parcela 1 :")
        for c in range(0, n):
            x = int(input())
            parcela1.append(x)
        print("Digite a sequência de inteiros da parcela 2 :")
        for c in range(0, n):
            x = int(input())
            parcela2.append(x)
    else:
        print("Valores gerados para a parcela 1 :", end=' ')
        for c in range(0, n):
            parcela1.append(random.randint(0, 9))
            print(parcela1[c], end=' ')
        print()
        print("Valores gerados para a parcela 2 :", end=' ')
        for c in range(0, n):
            parcela2.append(random.randint(0, 9))
            print(parcela2[c], end=' ')

    print()
    return parcela1, parcela2
```

Answer (score -2):

Uma função executa um algoritmo que retorna um valor.
A sua função inicial utiliza variáveis que precisam da interação do usuário para informar o que ele deseja.
Para você deixar apenas a função retornando as listas, precisará:

1. Retirar da função as requisições de informações do usuário
2. A Função passará a receber os valores das **variáveis como parâmetros** da função.

Ou seja, você precisa dividir sua função atual em duas partes, sendo a primeira parte o "aplicativo" que coletará as entradas necessárias que serão passadas como parâmetro para a função.

Com base no seu exemplo, teríamos que a função passa a prever o recebimento de 4 possíveis parâmetros `def entrada_soma(entrada,n,x1,x2):`.

### A Função

```
def entrada_soma(entrada,n,x1,x2):
    parcela1 = list()
    parcela2 = list()
    if entrada == 1:
        for c in range(0, n):
            parcela1.append(x1)
        for c in range(0, n):
            parcela2.append(x2)
    else:
        for c in range(0, n):
            parcela1.append(random.randint(0, 9))
        for c in range(0, n):
            parcela2.append(random.randint(0, 9))
    return parcela1, parcela2
```

Note que a função acima não requisita mais nada ao usuário, pois essa requisição estará separada da função.

### O Aplicativo utilizando a função

O Aplicativo será responsável por coletar as informações necessárias a serem passadas para a função como parâmetro e exibir o resultado recebido.

```
print("Digite a opção desejada :")
print("[1] - Valores pelo Teclado / [2] - Gerar aleatoriamente")
entrada = int(input())

print("Quantos inteiros cada sequência terá ?")
n = int(input())

x1 = 0  #  Declarando variáveis possíveis a serem utilizadas
x2 = 0  #  A segunda variável "x" que havia sido utilizada na função original

if entrada == 1:
    print("Digite a sequência de inteiros da parcela 1 :")
    x1 = int(input())
    print("Digite a sequência de inteiros da parcela 2 :")
    x2 = int(input())

p1, p2 = entrada_soma(entrada, n, x1, x2)

print("Valores gerados para a parcela 1 :", end=' ')
print(p1)
print("Valores gerados para a parcela 2 :", end=' ')
print(p2)
```

Busquei alterar o mínimo possível o nome de suas variáveis e não realizei análise da lógica do seu algoritmo. Aparentemente não está funcionando corretamente.

A função tem o objetivo de reutilizar código.
Não vejo como boa prática a realização de requisições ao usuário no corpo da função.
O aplicativo que fará a chamada da função é que será encarregado de fazer a coleta dos valores a serem repassados para a função como parâmetro.
A função deve declarar parâmetros que serão utilizados no corpo do algoritmo.

---

Abaixo, vamos fazer uma analogia com outro código, digamos que você tivesse o código seguinte e quisesse retirar as requisições da função:

### Função com prints e inputs

```
# Função com prints e requisições do usuário
def somaDoisNumeros():
    print('Soma de 2 números')
    print('Informe o primeiro número:')
    numero1 = int(input())
    print('Informe o segundo número:')
    numero2 = int(input())
    resultado = numero1 + numero2
    return resultado

# Aplicativo utilizando a função
soma = somaDoisNumeros()
print('A soma é:',soma)
```

Agora vamos retirar os prints e inputs da função, passando as requisições a serem realizadas ao usuário para o corpo do "aplicativo"

### Função **sem** prints nem inputs

```
# Função sem prints e sem requisições do usuário
def somaDoisNumeros(numero1, numero2):
    resultado = numero1 + numero2
    return resultado

# Aplicativo utilizando a função. Coleta entradas necessárias
print('Soma de 2 números')
print('Informe o primeiro número:')
n1 = int(input())

print('Informe o segundo número:')
n2 = int(input())

soma = somaDoisNumeros(n1, n2)
print('A soma é:',soma)
```

---

A principal finalidade da função é nos ajudar a organizar programas em pedaços que correspondam a como imaginamos uma solução do problema.

### Exemplo para solicitar opção do usuário

```
def lerOpcao():
    print("Informe como deseja gerar suas listas")
    print("[1] - Valores pelo Teclado")
    print("[2] - Gerar aleatoriamente")
    entrada = int(input())
    return entrada
```

Esta função `lerOpcao()` poderia ser chamada enquanto o usuário informasse um valor diferente de 1 ou 2 da seguinte forma:

```
opcao = 0
# Garantir que seja informada umas das opções possíveis
while opcao not in [1,2]:
    opcao = lerOpcao()
```

Dessa forma, foi criada uma função para solicitar a opção do usuário, não estou dizendo que é a melhor forma, mas você é que fará as funções conforme sua lógica de programação.

### Função para retornar lista dos números informados manualmente

Você poderia criar uma função para ser utilizada sempre que precisar que o usuário informa a lista do número que deverão constar na sequência, ondo o `n` será a quantidade de números da sequência, como no exemplo a seguir:

```
def lerNumerosManuais(n):
    lista = []
    print(f'Informe os {n} números da lista')
    for i in range(0,n):
        print("Informe um número :", end=' ')
        valor = int(input())
        lista.append(valor)
    return lista
```

Utilizaria a função `lerNumerosManuais` forma seguinte:

```
if opcao == 1:
    print("Digite a sequência de inteiros da parcela 1 :")
    parcela1 = lerNumerosManuais(n)
```

### Função para retornar lista dos números quando a opção for Aleatórios

```
def geraNumerosAleatorios(n):
    lista = []
    for i in range(0,n):
        valor = random.randint(0, 9)
        lista.append(valor)
    return lista
```

Exemplo da chamada:

```
parcela1 = geraNumerosAleatorios(n)
```

Espero que ajude.

Comment: Oi , em outros casos eu também não faria dessa forma kk , achei até estranho a possibilidade de poder fazer isso em python , na verdade eu fiz na tentativa de atender os requisitos de uma questão , segue a descrição do problema :  ----->           1. entrada() que far´a a entrada e sua verifica¸c˜ao e perguntar´a ao usu´ario qual o n´umero
de inteiros cada sequencia terá e se o usuário quer entrar com as sequencias de inteiros
ou se deseja gerá-las aleatoriamente. No segundo caso, utilize a biblioteca random para
gerar numeros pseudo-aleatorios para as duas listas:

Comment: Veja se eu entendi corretamente o problema. Na descrição do problema, entendi que você deve criar uma função para validar a entrada de dados do usuário. Acredito que deva verificar se o que o usuário informou é realmente um inteiro, por exemplo. Seria isso? Poderia reformular a descrição do problema para facilitar o entendimento?

Comment: Mais ou menos , adicionei uma imagem no arquivo , que mostra o enunciado .

Comment: @LailsonSan, não vi a imagem que mostra o enunciado. Foi realmente enviado?

Comment: Eu tinha colocado por algum motivo sumiu , todavia eu já enviei o arquivo incorreto mesmo , pra correção parcial , mesmo assim seria interessante pra mim sanar essa dúvida , se vc quiser mandar seu email posso te enviar , sou novo aqui , se não ta tranquilo kk !

Comment: Favor informar aqui mesmo, qual é o enunciado, para buscarmos melhorar a pergunta e a resposta de forma a ajudar tanto você quanto outros usuários que venham a ter uma dúvida semelhante.

Comment: Acho que agora foi , eu não tinha salvado

Comment: Agora consegui ver o enunciado em questão. Você quer realmente tirar todos os prints e inputs da função `entrada_soma()`? Pergunto, pelo motivo do enunciado informar que haverá interação do usuário para escolher (1) Tipo de geração das sequências, (2) Quantidade de números a serem informados / gerados para cada sequência. Sendo assim, se precisa de informação passada pelo usuário e esta função é a prevista pra coletar estas informações e retornar apenas as lista resultantes, acho que os `prints` e `inputs` são obrigatórios.

Comment: Sim exatamente , interpretei dessa forma , todavia toda vez que tento pegar os parâmetros que essa função retorna , a função executa novamente , eu não estava conseguindo guardar em uma lista sem que os parâmetros de dentro ficassem sem executar

Comment: Gostaria de saber se a função [entrada_soma()](https://ideone.com/8NzAPuT) do link resolveria seu problema? Nesta função, você teria a saída de uma lista `parcelas` em que cada item seria uma sequência ou parcela que poderá ser acessada posteriormente com o laço `for` conforme demonstro na função. Acesse a função clicando no link a seguir [ideone](https://ideone.com/8NzAPuT).